# Schur lemma and Whittaker functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $(\pi,V)$ be an infinite dimensional irreducible admissible representation of $\GL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. Let us fix an element $v_0\in V$ and define a vector space
$$V_{v_0} := \left\{\pi\begin{pmatrix}a& \\ &1\end{pmatrix}v_0,\;\text{s.t.}\;a\in \GL_1(\mathbb{Q}_p)\right\}.$$

We define the representation
\begin{align}\GL_1(\mathbb{Q}_p)&{}\to \operatorname{Aut}(V_{v_0}),\\ a&{}\mapsto \pi\begin{pmatrix}a& \\ &1\end{pmatrix}.\end{align}
It is irreducible and admissible since
$$\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}& \\ &1\end{pmatrix}\subseteq GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p).$$

On the one hand applying Schur's lemma for admissible representations (Lemma 4.2.4 of "[Automorphic forms and representations](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511609572)" of Bump) then the representation of $\GL_1(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ should satisfy that
$$\pi\begin{pmatrix}a& \\ &1\end{pmatrix}v_0 = \chi(a)v_0,$$
where $\chi$ is a character of $\GL_1(\mathbb{Q}_p)$.

On the other hand, let us suppose that $\pi\simeq \operatorname{Ind}_{P_{\GL_2}}^{\GL_2}\xi$, where $\xi$ is a character defined on the diagonal elements of $\GL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ such that $\pi$ is irreducible. We denote their Satake parameters by $\alpha_1,\;\alpha_2$ and the Whittaker functional by $W(\cdot)$. Theorem 4.6.5 of "[Automorphic forms and representations](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511609572)" of Bump states that
$$W\left(\pi\begin{pmatrix}p^k& \\ &1\end{pmatrix}v_0\right) = W(v_0)\frac{\alpha_1^{k+1}-\alpha_2^{k+1}}{\alpha_1-\alpha_2}.$$
The function
$$p^k\to \frac{\alpha_1^{k+1}-\alpha_2^{k+1}}{\alpha_1-\alpha_2},$$
is not a character for $(p)$. This contradicts the previous Schur's lemma argument. Where is the mistake in those computations?

Comment: Hi! Why should your representation of $GL_1(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ be irreducible?

Comment: Because the vector space $V_{v_0}$ is given by the translates of $v_0$. This representation does not admit a subrepresentation. For example given elements $v_1,\;v_2\in V_{v_0}$ by definition we can express $v_1 = \pi\begin{pmatrix}a_1& \\ & 1\end{pmatrix}v_0$ and $v_2 = \pi\begin{pmatrix}a_2& \\ & 1\end{pmatrix}v_0$. Therefore $\pi\begin{pmatrix}a_1^{-1}a_2& \\ & 1\end{pmatrix}v_1 = v_2$.

Comment: I don’t understand your first claim. What is $V_{v_0}$ supposed to be? As currently written, it isn’t a vector space. Even once that is clarified, I don’t get the irreducibility argument. What does the statement about units tell you?

Comment: You seem to be claiming that a cyclic representation (i.e. generated by a single element) is always irreducible. This is clearly false: think about the regular representation of $C_2$ (the cyclic group of order $2$).

Comment: There was a typo in the definition of $V_{v_0}$, now i have corrected it. What is the statement about units?

Comment: Are you assuming $v_0$ is a spherical vector? That might be the issue: the spherical vector is scaled by a character when acted on by compact diagonal elements, but not the full torus. The Whittaker formula (a special case of the Casselman-Shalika-Shintani formula) tells you how the full torus acts.

Comment: The set $V_{v_0}$ as you define it is still not a vector space (not stable under linear combinations!). In my comments I interpreted it as the vector space generated by the set your wrote.

Comment: I assume that you meant that $V_{v_0}$ is the span of these vectors? Even in this case, as other people have written here, the fact that it is a cyclic representation does not mean that it is irreducible.

Comment: The translates $\pi\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a& \\ &1\end{smallmatrix}\right)v_0$ span an infinite dimensional space, so the representation of $GL_1(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ on it is not irreducible. Infinite dimensionality is clear if you look at the support of each translate within the Kirillov model, which is the Whittaker model restricted to your subgroup $GL_1(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. See (6.12) on page 500 in Bump's book to get an idea of the support of the spherical vector $v_0$ in the Kirillov model. Then see what happens for $\pi\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a& \\ &1\end{smallmatrix}\right)v_0$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let me try to clarify. The formula for the Whittaker functional in Theorem 4.6.5 of "[Automorphic forms and representations](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511609572)" of Bump states that
$$W\left(\pi\begin{pmatrix}p^k& \\ &1\end{pmatrix}v_0\right) = W(v_0)\frac{\alpha_1^{k+1}-\alpha_2^{k+1}}{\alpha_1-\alpha_2},$$
where $v_0$ is a $\GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$-stable vector in the induced representation.

Your claim is then that the cyclic representation generated by $\GL_1(\mathbb{Q}_p)$-translates of $v_0$ is always irreducible as a $\GL_1(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ representation. As Aurel points out in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408555/schur-lemma-and-whittaker-functions#comment1047991_408555), this is certainly false in general. In the case related to the above formula, the fact that $v_0$ is $\GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$-stable does imply that $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ acts by a character since
$$\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}& \\ &1\end{pmatrix}\subseteq GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p),$$
but this says nothing about the action of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}p^{k}& \\ &1\end{pmatrix}
$$
for $k>0$. Those values are determined by the formula.